# Reference parameter being copied in variadic template

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

I have an Event class that stores a set of tuples of weak_ptr (the observer) to a function that gets executed when the event is "fired".

The function type is: void(int &) in the example.  That is to say, I want to fire the event passing a reference to a value, to have the observer change that value and to verify that the value was changed back in the observed object.  The event implementation is variadic by the way, which may complicate the issue (at least the code).

At the moment this is failing.  Somewhere along the line the reference is being converted to a non-reference or copied, but I cannot see where.

Full repo is below.  Note assert (value != 10) fails, even though I set the value to 1 in the event handler.

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

template<class FunctionPrototype>
class Event
{
public:

    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args)
    {
        for (auto const & listener : Listeners)
        {
            if (auto locked = std::get<0>(listener).lock())
                std::get<1>(listener)(args...);
        }       
    }

    template<typename P, typename Q, typename R, typename... Args>
    void Attach(P(Q::*f)(Args...), std::shared_ptr<R> const & p)
    {
        auto w = std::weak_ptr<R>(p);

        auto l = [w, f](Args... args) {
            if (auto locked = w.lock())
                return (*locked.get().*f)(args...);
            else
                return P();
        };

        Listeners.push_back(std::make_tuple(std::weak_ptr<void>(w), l));        
    }

    typedef std::tuple<std::weak_ptr<void>, std::function<FunctionPrototype>> event_tuple;

    std::vector<event_tuple> Listeners;
};

class Observed : public std::enable_shared_from_this < Observed >
{
public:

    int value;

    void Fire()
    {
        value = 10;

        TheEvent(value);

        assert(value != 10);
    }

    Event<void(int &)> TheEvent;
};

class Observer : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Observer>
{
public:

    void Attach(std::shared_ptr<Observed> const & observed)
    {
        observed->TheEvent.Attach(&Observer::OnEvent, shared_from_this());
    }

    void OnEvent(int & value)
    {
        assert(value == 10);

        value = 1;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    auto observed = std::make_shared<Observed>();
    auto observer1 = std::make_shared<Observer>();

    observer1->Attach(observed);
    observed->Fire();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Event::operator()` takes `args` by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event::operator()` takes arguments by value. Rewrite it as follows:

```
template<typename... Args>
void operator()(Args&&... args)
{
    for (auto const & listener : Listeners)
    {
        if (auto locked = std::get<0>(listener).lock())
            std::get<1>(listener)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }       
}
```

Comment: OK, but in a variadic parameter pack, I may want, for example, some to be by value and some by reference.  If I pass with &&, will that still happen?

Comment: Ah, I get the opposite problem.  So it seems I have to choose between passing by reference or by value. I can't mix them, ie. my function cannot be void (int, int &).

Comment: That should work. `OnEvent` can take its arguments however it likes. The fact that `Event::operator()` takes by reference doesn't change that.

Comment: Yes, I just did a test with int, int & and the first parameter wasn't changed, the second was.  So it works!  Thank you.

Comment: @Robinson [void(int, int&) works perfectly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1c2c3ccf38efdc2). `Event::operator()` takes all arguments by reference (whatever suitable for each argument) and passes them to the handler function which takes them by reference or by value, doesn't matter.